# Read file as binary - loop never ends

Tags: c++

I'm using the following code to open a file, read char by char and get the char number as hexadecimal. The problem is that the loop never ends. What is wrong with it?

Is file >> x the equivalent to x = file.get()?

```
ifstream file;
    file.open(argv[1], ifstream::in|ifstream::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        unsigned char x;

        file >> std::noskipws;
        while (file >> x) {

            stringstream s;
            s << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
                << (int)x;

            std::cout << s.str();
        }

        file.close();
    }
```

Comment: How are you determining that the loop never ends? It doesn't look wrong at all. Did you copy and paste that or type it from memory? Retyping has a fantastic way of getting rid of bugs for you.

Comment: I've run the code for a 1mb file and it never stops printing the elements. I just copied the code from Visual Studio.

Comment: Actually, I have waited 2 minutes to print every byte of the file (1MB) in a new test. Should I read a block and execute the hex function in a inner loop?

Comment: A 1 MB file isn't a very good testcase - use a small one (just a few characters) containing a string that you recognise immediately so you know the output is correct. And you're wasting a *lot* of time building a `stringstream` for each character. Just send the output directly to `std::cout`.

Comment: I'm sending the value to a stringstream for further processing, in my final code it won't be printing this value on screen, it will send it to a new file. Should I use a different data type instead of stringstream?

Comment: Then you could output directly to that file stream instead. `stringstream` is mostly used if you want to build a string for some other reason than to immediately write it to another stream.

Comment: But should I keep looping on every byte or should I read blocks?

Comment: Try the simplest thing first. If that's too slow, do the complicated thing. If that doesn't work, ask again.